# Objeto filho aparece como 'undefined', mas um nível anterior do objeto mostra o valor

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

O campo `this.props.usuario.user.guia` está como `undefined`, mas quando boto no log o objeto `this.props.usuario.user` aparece com valor. Isso não faz sentido para mim.

Código do log:

```
if (!this.props.usuario.logout) { 
    if (prevProps.usuario.user !== this.props.usuario.user) {
        console.tron.log(this.props.usuario);
        console.tron.log(this.props.usuario.user);
        console.tron.log(this.props.usuario.user.guia);
    }
}
```

[image: Imagem do resultado do LOG]

Comment: Por que não faz sentido? Um objeto filho pode estar vazio, impossível seria o objeto estar vazio e ter um objeto filho com valor....!

Comment: Bom dia! A imagem não está bem explicita ao que corresponde.. O segundo item de debug refere-se a que? Podes mostrar o resultado dos console?

Comment: Bom dia! Realmente está difícil decifrar o código acima, tente colocar somente o console.log() da linha que funciona e o outro da linha que da erro comentado do lado direito!! ;)

Comment: Seguinte gente, quando eu coloco no meu log o objeto this.props.usuario.user ele me mostra aqueles itens da imagem(user, turista, nome...) com valor, porém quando eu tento usar o this.props.usuario.user.guia, por exemplo, ele me apresenta undefined, sendo q no log, da linha anterior, ele apresentava valor

Comment: aquela linha undefined da imagem do log é representada pelo comando console.tron.log(this.props.usuario.user.guia);. Já a linha com valor é representada pelo console.tron.log(this.props.usuario.user);

Comment: 1. O segundo bloco de log não seria this.props.usuario? Se sim, o certo não seria this.props.usuario.guia? 2. Outra tentativa: Será que o objeto não está como string? Tente JSON.parse(this.props.usuario.user).guia ... Não consigo pensar em outra situação, mas sugiro observar se não existe nada assincrono rolando que pode estar alterando o estado da sua aplicação e causando esses problemas.